# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Gamemaker 2

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I get the error when i compile to HTML target, but not when I use OSX target.

I have the same error on 4 other objects.  New to Gamemaker, so having issues on where to look.  If I were in another platform I would be able to understand where I had screwed up.

```
/// @desc add the gun to be part of the player
x = oPlayer.x;
y = oPlayer.y + 10 ;

image_angle = point_direction(x,y,mouse_x,mouse_y);  //gun points toward mouse

firingdelay = firingdelay -1; // we we can only shoot every x frames see delay = 5 below
recoil = max(0,recoil -1); // max retrund the biggets of the values given  stops us getting a minus number i.e nolower than 0.

if (mouse_check_button(mb_left)) &&  (firingdelay < 0)
{
    recoil = 4;
    firingdelay = 5;
    ScreenShake(2,10); // add some shake to screen when we fire
    
    with (instance_create_layer(x,y,"Bullets",oBullet))
    {
        speed = 25; // fixed speed for the object
        direction = other.image_angle + random_range(-3,3); //other.  is the orginal object outside this created bullet so the gun  the random raange  offfset the direction a little to get a spread
        image_angle = direction;
    }
}
x = x - lengthdir_x(recoil,image_angle);
y = y - lengthdir_y(recoil,image_angle);

if  (image_angle > 90) &&  (image_angle < 270) //90 is right , 270 is down  this is saying are we left
{
    image_yscale = -1;  
}
else
{
    image_yscale = 1;   
}



ERROR
```

Compiling - gml_Object_oGun_Create_0
Compiling - gml_Object_oGun_Step_1
Error : gml_Object_oGun_Step_1(0) : Fatal Error while compiling gml_Object_oGun_Step_1 - bailing details below
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException () [0x0000c] in :0
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x00009] in :0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter , System.Boolean ) [0x00886] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x00287] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x0005a] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter , System.Boolean ) [0x000a1] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x00287] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x0005a] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x0019c] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x00287] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x0005a] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter , System.Boolean ) [0x000a1] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMLToken , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x00050] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0
at .. (GMAssetCompiler.GMAssets , . , System.IO.TextWriter ) [0x002d9] in <07e707e963e944de851ed00054ecf0f5>:0

Comment: Could you show us the error message? Usually that one explains where the error occurs.

Comment: added to the post :)

Comment: This is not the code that throws the exception. There seems to be an issue with the tool you are using.

Comment: that's what I thought.  Hmm, I am just using gamemaker 2 can coying the error from the output window and the code from Ogun which I link to from the compile error window. Not sure where I am going wrong; maybe i am not understanding the IDE